# tutorials or url on how to design an etl that loads data in Dimension table in sql 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

How can design an ETL that is able to load new records  in dimension table  and automically primary keys or surrogate keys are assigned to new records in a dimension table. Please help  with Tutorial or explanations on how to insert records in a dimension table and primary keys are being inserted automatically??I am using SQL 2008 r 2

Answer (score 2):

[Todd McDermid](http://toddmcdermid.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-load-dimension-tables-with.html) is wicked smart, assuming you're using the [DimensionMergeSCD component](http://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/)

[SQLServerPedia](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SSIS_-_Slowly_Changing_Dimension_Wizard) has a lightweight article

[Jork Klein](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2010/02/28/ssis-package-design-pattern-for-loading-a-data-warehouse-part-2.aspx) has a nice series using the SCD wizard

[Brian Knight](http://www.sqlshare.com/loading-a-dimension-with-the-ssis-slowly-changing-dimension-wizard_158.aspx) has a video on it if you're into that sort of thing

[Karan Gulati](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karang/archive/2010/09/29/slowly-changing-dimension-using-ssis.aspx) has a post as well